# Vuetify 2 - dynamic bind of component type

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

In Vuetify 1.5 we could bind a component type dynamically at runtime using `<component :is="type" .../>` where type could be for e.g `'v-combobox'`.

In Vuetify 2 this non longer seems to work and we're seeing an `'component v-combobox cannot be found...'` type errors.

This is of particular interest for the combobox / autocomplete components where we are using these in a HOC and need to toggle between the functionality offered by these distinct components (why are they distinct btw????).

Any idea how to do this in Vuetify 2?

Thanks much.

Comment: Are you using combobox & autocomplete elsewhere in your code so the vuetify-loader is loading them properly? If not you have to locally load those components into your component. (see [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte#limitations))

Comment: @asi please add your code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please add codesandbox or any code snippets.
Component "is" attribute will work only if component registered locally where "is" refer to that component name.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the [migration docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte#limitations) and as indicated in the comments to the question I do need to register the components locally first.

It's worth pointing out that I am using these components elsewhere in the app but vuetify-loader does not seem to pick them out without explicit local registration.